# Why can't bitwise operators be used directly in stream?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

While trying to run this code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  short int a = 0xFFFD, b = 10;
  cout <<  a | b;
  return 0;
}
```

I got an error

> error : no match for 'operator|'

However, storing the result in another variable seems to solve the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  short int a = 0xFFFD, b = 10, c;
  c = a | b;
  cout << c;
  return 0;
}
```

Could somebody explain me why?

Comment: That's because of ooperator precedence.

Comment: Make it `cout <<  (a | b);` You don't need an extra variable, just a well-placed pair of parentheses.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Answers go in the answer section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cout <<  a | b;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
(cout << a) | b;
```

If you read the rest of the error message, you'll see that it's telling you there no `operator|(ostream&, short int)`, which is true.

Fix your expression by putting parens in the proper place:

```
cout << (a | b);
```

(Pre-storing `a | b` in its own variable has a similar effect.)

Yes, this is unintuitive here, but that's because `<<` has been "re-used" from its base meaning of "bitwise left shift", and due to that base meaning it was originally decided that `|` would have a lower *precedence* than `<<`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that bitwise operator | has a lower priority compared with the shift operator.

Thus this statement

```
cout <<  a | b;
```

is equivalent to the statement

```
( cout <<  a ) | b;
```

and there is no overloaded operator | for the left operand of type `std::osteram`